# Avoiding a user registration system but need in app purchases and data synced

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble understanding the theory of in-app purchases and have got to the point where I read so much I have confused myself.

I have an application where I don't require the user to register however I do store data on a server and track this using the UUID. My application scrapes a hi-score system for an online game and the user has to input which players on the online game they wish to keep track of. This information is then sent to my server which scrapes the data every 24 hours by default. Here is an example of the database on my server.

Devices Table:
uuid,
scrape_interval

Players being tracked table:
uuid,
player_name

Tracking information table:
player_name,
track_data,
tracked_on

I want to include an in-app purchase which once purchased will mean that data is scraped every 12 hours instead of every 24 hours, the way I plan to do this is by updating the devices table and set the scrape_interval to 12 hours where uuid = uuid that made the purchase.

However how will this work for users that have multiple IOS devices, how do I ensure the list of players they are tracking is kept sync across devices? I have read about using an iCloud ID which is apparently a unique identifier but does this mean I will have to do a check on the launch of my app to ensure the user is logged into an iCloud account and force them to login if they aren't? This doesn't seem very user-friendly but nor does implementing a custom registration and login system.

Am I over thinking? Is there a simple solution?

Comment: Just wondering how do you find out if a user made a purchase from the different device? Don't the user needs to log into itunes again in different device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app purchases can be restored across multiple devices associated with a single itunes account. So a single purchase may actually exist on 5 devices, and you can not tell which is which.

The IAP will provide no device specific id. Your only option is to generate a unique installation id and sync all installation ids that have the paid status.

Comment: So would this be a suitable implementation?

- Track UUIDs in database, when IAP is made update database to flag that UUID as a purchaser.
- If purchases are restored on another device, also mark that UUID as a purchased.

I will just have to accept the fact that this is open to slight abuse if people share their iTunes credentials?

Comment: Yes, I take this approach. This method then also works when people switch platforms and expect the purchase from one to carry to another. People can only share the itunes account for I believe 5 authorized devices. Plus you can use the restore purchase process to check if that device is still using the previous itunes account if you want to get very picky. Google play allows you to query the state of the user purchases very easily if you are going IAB as well.